# Shell: Does "a -lt b" not mean true if a is less than b?  

Tags: linux, shell

I'm not trained in Linux, but I can muddle through with some doc lookups, but I'm stumped.

I found a script that helps set the date on my dd wrt router when it starts up, but only if the current date is less than the stored date.  I can share the whole script if you want, but it boils down to this statement not evaluating to true when I expect it to.  I'm putting the literals in, rather than the variables, and it still does not return true, it executes the "else" statement:

```
 if [ 021715402012 -lt 021815402012 ]
  then
     echo "the first seems less than the second"
  else
     echo "the first does not seem less than the second for some reason"
  fi
```

I would expect "the first seems less than the second" but this is not the case...
Is it an overflow problem?  I tried to make it a string compare like this:

```
if [ x021715402012 -lt x021815402012 ]
```

and tried putting it in quotes:

```
if [ "x021715402012" -lt "x021815402012" ]
```

it always executes the else.  Does "`a -lt b`" not mean true if a is less than b?

Any insight into this would be appreciated, I'm stumped!

Comment: Works fine in `bash` on my Mac.

Comment: Hmm it prints "the first seems less than the second" for me when i test your example. What bash or sh version is this? If you want more information about -lt etc you can check `help test`, `help [` or `man test`.

Comment: Also works fine on my openwrt router.  But I clearly have a different implementation that you do, because mine gives "bad number" with the `x` included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mnemonics such as `-lt` might be said to come from the original Fortran comparators such as `.LT.` from the late 1950s.

Yes, in the shell, `-lt` does a 'less than' numeric comparison.  (Be aware, though, that in Perl, the numeric comparisons are `<` etc, and the string comparisons are denoted by the alphabetic operators such as `-lt`!)

However, in some, perhaps many, shells the conversion and comparison may well be done in the local long integer format.  If you're on a 32-bit machine, the values you quote exceed the 32-bit (signed) range by a factor of 10 or so. On a 64-bit machine, or with a shell that uses `long long`, you'd be OK.

The hex equivalents of the decimal numbers are 021715402012 = 0x50E56BD1C and 021815402012 = 0x5144C9E1C; they can't be octal because of the 8.  (However, if the shell does interpret the leading zero as 'octal', then the second number is just 021 or 17 decimal because the 8 ends the octal number.  However, the 64-bit shells I tested on (Mac OS X 10.7.3 and RHEL 5) both seemed to treat them as decimal, not octal.)

The example code below, compiled under 64-bit gives the following output:

```
021715402012 =  240565532 = 0x050E56BD1C
021815402012 =  340565532 = 0x05144C9E1C
```

Compiled under 32-bit, it gives the following output:

```
021715402012 = 2147483647 = 0x007FFFFFFF
021815402012 = 2147483647 = 0x007FFFFFFF
```

If this was what happened in your shell, then the resulting behaviour of `-lt` would be explained.  You could confirm it by testing whether the two values are `-eq`; counter-intuitively, this would probably evaluate to true under the hypothesis that you are using a 32-bit shell that limits its arithmetic to `long` (32-bit) signed integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *array[] = { "021715402012", "021815402012" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        int j = atoi(array[i]);
        long k = strtol(array[i], 0, 10);
        printf("%-10s = %10d = 0x%.10lX\n", array[i], j, k);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan for such a thorough response.  I believe the issue is the overflow condition, they are simply both too large.  I removed the 2012 at the end of each, and it started acting as expected, even with the leading zero. So the octal compare theory was not the case here.  As these numbers are actually dates in a strange order of characters (mmddHHMMyyyy) I will split the compare to compare the years first then the mmddHHMM, and I believe that will solve this problem.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

What shell and version are you using? Any chance of an embedded control character somewhere?  (Try deleting re-typing the code.)  On openSUSE 11.2 (x86_64):

```
$if [ 021715402012 -lt 021815402012 ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes
```

Interestingly, though,

```
$if [ 012 -lt 11 ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
no
```

This surprises me because `man bash` says that `-lt` performs an arithmetic comparison, and a constant with a leading 0 is interpreted as octal.  So I'd expect this to test whether ten is less than eleven, because 012 base 8 = 8 + 2.

Can someone set us straight?

Comment: I got "no" as well.  The problem was as @Jonathan said above - the numbers were too large and so, I presume, interpreted to be the same. I confirmed this by changing -lt to -gt.  It still said "no"  If not gt and not lt, must be equal, then... in the eyes of a little router.

Answer (score 1):

A few things are happening...

Your shell seems to be using 32-bit arithmetic and your numbers are overflowing the format.

Also, all command parameters in shell scripts are strings, so the quotes will have no effect at all unless characters in a parameter are significant to the shell parser.

The shell `if` statement is actually running [the test(1) command](http://man.he.net/man1/test) which is linked to `[` as a shorthand. (And then it ignores a final `]`.) Although the command could have used the same operator for numeric and string comparisons, as it happens the command is designed in such a way that the operators assume a certain type, and `-lt` assumes numeric.

On bash and ash (dash) I get an error message on your *x...* example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your particular shell is using this interpretation, but here's what I think is happening:

`021715402012` is an 11-digit octal number.  `021815402012` is a two-digit octal number terminated by a non-octal digit (the `8`).

Of `021715402012` and `021`, clearly the second is smaller.

Regarding your other attempts, the documentation for the `test` and `[` commands indicates that `-lt` is only valid for numeric arguments, not strings.

Comment: Interesting hypothesis; the acid test is to drop the leading zero.  The `x` version will compare equal, won't it, because both strings evaluate to zero a numerics.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Probably.  Let me see if my openwrt box can reproduce the original behavior.... actually I get the "expected" behavior with the leading zeros, and with 'x' I get "ash: x021715402012: bad number".